# Can you hook into a Redactor field before render?

Tags: redactor, hook

I am wanting to hook into all my redactor fields content before rendering and update any inline links to include a title="" attribute. Is it possible to hook into the field before it is rendered? With PHP or in settings (https://imperavi.com/redactor/docs/settings/)?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably several ways you could tackle this like with a custom Redactor JS plugin, but I'd probably write a Craft plugin that forked and extended the original Craft Redactor plugin.

From there, you could overwrite the Redactor field's `normalizeValue()` method and parse the input to make whatever changes you want before returning.